# G suite account , accessing user's drive

Tags: google-drive-api

As an admin of G suite account, is there a way to access a domain user's G Drive data with Google Drive API, but with by passing the authorization screen?
In other words, the OAuth2.0 is setup for each user without need the user to interact with Google directly.

If possible a web code sample in C# would help.
Thanks
B

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be done using Drive API but you can try and use Admin SDK. You can use this to create a [Drive Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-drive) and transfer data using [Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#perform_g_suite_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority) is exactly what you're looking for.

Service accounts are used for impersonating a user, avoiding their human interaction for authorizarion.

Depending on the [scopes](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#drivev3) you use, you'll be able to define the level of access you want for your app.

You may find a sample [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service-account).

Comment: Hi cjlallana, 
Thank for your answer. I did as you advised and man aged to do so.
However,  there is a speed problem when comes to large files so we thought about uploading with JS.
That means, that instead of having the user first upload to our server and then we will call the API on server side, it will be uploaded directly to the storage.
Problem is that JS is exposed to the end user which is something we are trying to avoid.Is there a way to authenticate the user on server with the service account and then establish connection in the JS and perform what's needed?maybe to hide the JS?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to use a Service Account in Javascript without having security risks, like you mentioned, as you would be exposing your client secrets. -- 
For uploading large files, it is recomended using Resumable Uploads, which lets you chunk the file into smaller parts, although I'm not sure if that would make the upload faster: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/resumable-upload

Comment: thanks again. so, would you recommend for security reason to use server 2 server upload and not JS? does the resumable works as "fire and forget" so the user can upload and leave it for processing? I assume that server 2 server will require first upload to our server and then to the storage?this will slow down the process , no?

Comment: btw, speaking of JS, i saw an option to authenticate on the server, and return a token to the client JS and then to use the gapi. is it not possible to do the authentication with service account the same way? i managed to do so but got an error saying some like exceeding the daily request number... so i think it doesn't work well...